# Java - retrieve data from plsql stored procedure with user defined in and out parameters

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have to call a pl/sql stored procedure from java. The stored procedure has in and out parameters that are user definded as Objects.
I have defined the classes that implements SQLData class for mapping the database object into a java object.

This is my code to call the stored procedure

```
private String procedure = "{call READ_METADATA(?,?,?,?)}";
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbConnectionUrl, username, password);
CallableStatement cstmt = conn.prepareCall(procedure);

Map metaDataMap = conn.getTypeMap();
metaDataMap.put("METADATA", Class.forName("mypackage.TMetaData"));
conn.setTypeMap(metaDataMap);

Map resultMap = conn.getTypeMap();
resultMap.put("RESULT", Class.forName("mypackage.TResult"));
conn.setTypeMap(resultMap);

Object[] callerArray = new Object[4];

callerArray[0] = "";
callerArray[1] = "";
callerArray[2] = codeApplication;
callerArray[3] = codeFacility;
Struct struct = conn.createStruct("CALLER", callerArray);

cstmt.setObject(1, struct);
cstmt.setString(2, fdnSequenceId.toString());
cstmt.registerOutParameter(3, OracleTypes.STRUCT, "METADATA");
cstmt.registerOutParameter(4, OracleTypes.STRUCT, "RESULT");
cstmt.executeUpdate();
```

Than i retrieve the data from stored procedure in this way

```
TMetaData metadati = (TMetaData)cstmt.getObject(3, metaDataMap);
TResult result = (TResult)cstmt.getObject(4, resultMap);
```

This is the stored procedure definition

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE READ_METADATA
(
    param_caller IN CALLER,
    param_sequence_id IN VARCHAR2,
    param_metadata OUT METATADA,
    param_result OUT RESULT
);
```

The problem is that the object METADATA contains NULL value and the result object contains '???' in all fields.

If i call the stored procedure from SQL Developer it works.

Comment: Is the java class mypackage.TMetaData   implementing one of these interface (sqldata,oradata) ?

Comment: It implements SQLData

Comment: Attach implementation of this class.

Comment: It was only an encoding problem. I've added the orai18n.jar library to the project and now it works.